# Using a variable to replace portion of code? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I get the var sliderthumb to replace [sliderthumb] in my code below? Thanks for your help.

```
var sliderthumb:String = "foo";

function natureThumb(){

Sprite(naturepage.sliders.[sliderthumb].getChildAt(1)).height = Sprite(naturepage.sliders.[sliderthumb].getChildAt(1)).width = 65;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the dot.

```
Sprite(naturepage.sliders[sliderthumb].getChildAt(1)).height
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method for `displayObjectContainer` called `getChildByName` that allow to access child display objects by its name. Hope this helps!

```
var sliderthumb:String = "foo";

function natureThumb(){

Sprite(naturepage.sliders.getChildByName(sliderthumb).getChildAt(1)).height = Sprite(naturepage.sliders.getChildByName(sliderthumb).getChildAt(1)).width = 65;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well both answers provided can sorta be right depending on how the OP set things up, but wanted to add some clarification.  First I would modify the code to be this:

```
var sliderthumb:String = "foo";

function natureThumb(){
    var sp:Sprite = naturepage.sliders.[sliderthumb].getChildAt(1) as Sprite;
    sp.height = sp.width = 65;
}
```

if you setup the object like

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
mySprite.id = "foo";
```

then this will work (assuming you want the second child of the object foo which is a child of sliders)

```
function natureThumb(){
    var sp:Sprite = naturepage.sliders[sliderthumb].getChildAt(1) as Sprite;
    sp.height = sp.width = 65;
}
```

if you instead setup your object like

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
mySprite.name = "foo";
```

then this will work

```
function natureThumb(){
    var sp:Sprite = naturepage.sliders.getChildByName(sliderthumb).getChildAt(1) as Sprite;
    sp.height = sp.width = 65;
}
```